How do nonlinear relationships affect casuality determination
Let's assume that I have only one independent variable and one dependent, and I have a great model with minimal error which deals well with predicting. Let's also assume that I do no know the true causal relationship between X and Y (which one is a cause and which is a result).
Case 1: model is linear: y(x)= ax+b In such case, I can both predict Y by X and vice versa
Case 2: model is nonlinear: y(x)= ax^2+bx+c In such a case, I can only predict Y by X, but not X by Y since predicting X by Y will return 2 values
Question: Can the non-linearity as in "case 2" be a clue or indicator regarding the true causal relationship between X and Y? Or maybe can it indicate that while predicting X by Y there is some third hidden variable involved?
Thank you very much!

This is probably more a question for the artists on stats stackexchange who have more experience with data. Naively I would think that as long as we cannot rule out a hidden variable that decides to which branch of $X$ it jumps when $Y$ comes in we can never be sure that $X$ causally determines $Y$ and not the other way round.
